# Wordpress OptimizePress - Getting a random border

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wordpress OptimizePress for my internship. I am upgrading his website with making helping videos for his customers and putting them in his website. After I added some text and video's, suddenly there was a border... First it was around my video in the upper right. Then I have added a title above it. But after that the title got a border. So now im stuck with my website with a random border around the title in the right.

Someone has any idea or some help about OptimizePress?

The Website: https://www.ritty.nl/installatie/

Comment: It's time for you to learn about CSS.  Right-click the offending element (the border) and do "Inspect" to see why you're getting borders.  There are several WordPress plugins allowing you to add CSS rules to your site, so you can override default styles and get precisely the appearance you want.

Comment: Oke thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

In Custom-CSS

```
#le_body_row_2_col_2 {border: none !important;}
```

should fix the problem